# c# Linq vs foreach

Tags: c#, performance, comparative-review, xamarin

which better in performance

consider that case I have an array of objects (`DocsOrder`), I looped throw that array to match exists of passed data `itemTapped.DocType`

I can take one of two approaches

**First One**

```
foreach (var pdt in DocsOrder)
                {
                    if (pdt != itemTapped.DocType) continue;
                    await GetPdf(pdt, isImage2, itemTapped.Title);
                    bPDfOk = true;
                    break;
                }
```

**Second One**

```
if (DocsOrder.Any(x => x == itemTapped.DocType))
                {
                    await GetPdf((PdfDocType)itemTapped.DocType , isImage2, itemTapped.Title);
                    bPDfOk = true;
                }
```

which one is faster and better for performance or both are the same

Comment: these are not even doing the same thing :/ Which one is correct?

Comment: why you said they don't do the same it should be

Comment: The first one does have the possibility to call `GetPdf` more than once

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Besides the difference in the two approaches (the first actually iterates over a collection, the second does not unless you call `Where()` instead of `Any()`, and it looks like this specific case calls for `foreach` anyway since you're not projecting), if you want to know how two different pieces of code perform, just benchmark them with `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`. There's no other way to know for you, nor for us. A rule of thumb is that LINQ is a tad slower, but you can't say for sure until you measure.

Comment: this condition I user as validation if (DocsOrder.Any(x => x == itemTapped.DocType))  this why I used Any , and I prefer Linq as when I find the item I looking for it will stop iteration but foreach keep looping

Comment: The code fragments do the same thing and there is no possibility to call `GetPdf` more than once.

Comment: Since you only want to get one pdf, I'd consider a loop to send the wrong 'signal'. An `Any` or `FirstOrDefault` call makes the intent of the code more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the performance point of view, there is no significant difference between the 2 solutions. Therefore, try to write the code as readable as possible.

If `DocType` is a reference type (and `itemTapped.DocType` can not be null), I would restructure the code to something like that:

```
var docType = DocsOrder.FirstOrDefault(x => x == itemTapped.DocType);
if (docType != null)
{
    await GetPdf(docType, isImage2, itemTapped.Title);
    bPDfOk = true;
}
```

otherwise I would prefer a slightly different version of the second option:

```
var hasTabbedType = DocsOrder.Any(x => x == itemTapped.DocType);
if (hasTabbedType)
{
    await GetPdf((PdfDocType)itemTapped.DocType , isImage2, itemTapped.Title);
    bPDfOk = true;
}
```

Whatever `bPDfOk` is meant for - I would try to avoid such flags... ;)